# How should I test Servlet Filters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, servlet-filters

having trouble figuring out how to test my servlet filters

```
@Component
@Order( Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE )
class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger( CORSFilter.class );

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response,
            final FilterChain filterChain )
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        log.debug( "request: {}", request );
        response.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" );
        response.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE" );
        response.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type, x-auth-token, x-requested-with" );
        response.setHeader( "Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Location" );
        response.setIntHeader( "Access-Control-Max-Age", 3600 );
        filterChain.doFilter( request, response );
    }
}
```

here's what I've tried writing test wise

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@WebAppConfiguration
@ComponentScan( "com.xenoterracide.rpf.infrastructure.http")
@SpringApplicationConfiguration( classes = { MockServletContext.class } )
public class TestHeaders {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;
    private MockMvc               mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup( context ).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCORS() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform( options( "/" ) )
                    .andExpect( status().is2xxSuccessful() )
                    .andExpect( header().string( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                            allOf( notNullValue(), instanceOf( String.class ) ) ) );
    }

}
```

here's my test error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Response header Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Expected: (not null and an instance of java.lang.String)
 but: not null was null
```

how can I test that my servlet filters are functioning correctly? bonus points if testing them doesn't require loading the full context, db and all.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[You can register a `Filter` instance in your `MockMvc`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/setup/AbstractMockMvcBuilder.html#addFilter-javax.servlet.Filter-java.lang.String...-)

```
this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup( context )
                              .addFilter(new CORSFilter(), "/*")
                              .build();
```

Comment: What's important here is that mockMvc was built manually. If using autoconfigured mockMvc all available filters in test context will be added to it, which in my case led to undesirable effects while testing spring security.