# Testing WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

This is my test, I'm adding additional header tests [after testing my filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30408391/206466)

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@WebAppConfiguration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@SpringApplicationConfiguration( classes = {
        MockServletContext.class,
        HttpSessionConfig.class,
        WebSecurityConfig.class
} )
@SuppressWarnings( "PMD.TooManyStaticImports" )
public class HeadersTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc = null;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup( context )
                .addFilter( new CORSFilter(), "/*" )
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testOptions() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform( options( "/" ) )
                .andExpect( status().is2xxSuccessful() )
                .andExpect( header().string( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", notNullValue() ) )
                .andExpect( header().string( "Access-Control-Allow-",
                        equalToIgnoringCase( "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE" ) ) )
                .andExpect( header().string( "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                        equalToIgnoringCase( "content-type, x-auth-token, x-requested-with" ) ) )
                .andExpect( header().string( "Access-Control-Expose-Headers", equalToIgnoringCase( "Location" ) ) )
                .andExpect( header().string( "Access-Control-Max-Age", notNullValue() ) )
        ;
    }    
}
```

the test works if I remove `WebSecurityConfig.class` from the configuration, but when I add it I get this exception

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor]
```

this is `WebSecurityConfig`

```
@Configuration
@Order( SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER - 1 )
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure( final HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/" ).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

How can I change my test so that the `WebSecurityConfig` properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to work but seems significantly heavier, so maybe their's a lighter/faster answer?

I added

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
}
```

and loaded it, as well as adding `@WebAppConfiguration` and my `WebSecurityConfig` classes,

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@SpringApplicationConfiguration( classes = {
        MockServletContext.class,
        HttpSessionConfig.class,
        WebSecurityConfig.class,
        Application.class
} )
public class HeadersTest {
```

and now the test passes again, as well as adding a test that checks for `X-Frame-Options`